# If $\phi \in C^1_c(\mathbb R)$ then $ \lim_n \int_\mathbb R \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\phi(x)\,dx = \pi\phi(0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Let $\phi \in C^1_c(\mathbb R)$. Prove that $$
> \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_\mathbb R \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\phi(x) \, dx = \pi\phi(0).
> $$

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to give a complete proof. First of all, I fixed $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists a $\delta >0$ s.t. 
$$
\vert x \vert < \delta \Rightarrow \vert \phi(x)-\phi(0) \vert < \frac{\varepsilon}{\pi}.
$$
Now, I would use the well-known fact that 
$$
\int_\mathbb R \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = \pi.
$$
On the other hand, by substitution rule, we have also
$$
\int_\mathbb R \frac{\sin(nx)}{x} \, dx = \int_\mathbb R \frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx = \pi.
$$
Indeed, I would like to estimate the quantity
$$
\begin{split}
& \left\vert \int_\mathbb R \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\phi(x) \, dx - \pi \phi(0) \right\vert = \\ 
& = \left\vert \int_\mathbb R \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\phi(x) \, dx - \phi(0)\int_\mathbb R \frac{\sin{(nx)}}{x}dx \right\vert \le \\ 
& \le \int_\mathbb R \left\vert \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\right\vert \cdot \left\vert  \phi(x)-\phi(0) \right\vert dx
\end{split}
$$
but the problem is that $x \mapsto \frac{\sin(nx)}{x}$ is not absolutely integrable over $\mathbb R$. Another big problem is that I don't see how to use the hypothesis $\phi$ has compact support.

I think that I should use dominated convergence theorem, but I've never done exercises about this theorem. Would you please help me? Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that
$$
\small
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\phi(x)dx-\pi\phi(0)=
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\phi(x)dx-\phi(0)\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}dx=
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\left(\phi(x)-\phi(0)\right)dx
$$
Denote
$$
\small
I_{m}(n):=\int\limits_{[-\pi m,\pi m]}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\left(\phi(x)-\phi(0)\right)dx\qquad
I(n):=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\left(\phi(x)-\phi(0)\right)dx
$$
We claim that $I_m(n)$ converges to $I(n)$ uniformly by $n\in\mathbb{N}$ when $m\to\infty$. Indeed, since $\phi$ is compactly supported
$$
\small
\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left|I_m(n)-I(n)\right|=
\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left|\;\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\pi m,\pi m]}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\left(\phi(x)-\phi(0)\right)dx\right|=
$$
$$
\small
\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left|\;\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\pi m,\pi m]}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}(-\phi(0))dx\right|=
\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left|\phi(0)\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\pi mn,\pi mn]}\frac{\sin(y)}{y}dy\right|=
$$
$$
\small
|\phi(0)|\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\left|\;\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\pi m,\pi m]}\frac{\sin(y)}{y}dy\right|=0
$$
Since convergence is uniform by $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we can say
$$
\small
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} I(n)=
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \lim\limits_{m\to\infty} I_m(n)=
\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} I_m(n)=
\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{[-\pi m,\pi m]}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\left(\phi(x)-\phi(0)\right)dx
$$
Since $\varphi\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R})$, then the function $x^{-1}(\varphi(x)-\varphi(0))$ is in $L^1([-\pi m,\pi m])$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Then by [Riemann–Lebesgue lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma)
$$
\small
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_{[-\pi m,\pi m]}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\left(\phi(x)-\phi(0)\right)dx=0
$$
so $\small\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}I(n)=0$. This is exactly what we wanted to prove.

Comment: What a simple and excellent proof! Thank you very much for your kindness.

Comment: @Romeo, not at all

Comment: I saw the edit, but not how to get the bound.

Comment: Davide, it is more possible for me to mistake then you not to see the bound

Comment: Note that $\varphi$ is compcatly supported, then does its derivative. So we can integrate over support of $\phi$. The measure  of support is finite (since support is bounded) and derivative is bounded since it is continuous

Comment: @Norbert : Sir, what is $\xi$ here. Looks like a very nice problem.

Comment: But we integrate when $y/n$ is in the support of $\phi$/$\phi'$, so the set is larger.

Comment: Thanks, Davide! I'll salvage this proof, wait a minute please.

Comment: @Theorem $\xi(x)$ is a point on $[o,x]$ given by mean value theorem

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Is it correct now?

Comment: So your question about equality $$\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-m,m]}\frac{\sin(y)}{y}dy=0$$?

Comment: No, the equality between the RHS of your comment and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sup_n\left|\int_{x\geq nm}\frac{\sin x}x\right|$.

Comment: I believe that for each $m$ there exist $k>m$ such that $$\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left|\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-mn,mn]} \frac{\sin(y)}{y}dy\right|=\left|\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-k,k]} \frac{\sin(y)}{y}dy\right|$$

Comment: @Norbert I've not checked whether it's true. Maybe it would be simpler if we work with $\int_{mn\pi}\frac{\sin y}y dy$ (instead of $mn$ as lower bound, I mean).

Comment: Davide Giraudo, thanks for your helpful suggestions!

Comment: I thank you both for the great work you're doing: I'm reading what you wrote ad I'm learning a lot of things. Thank you very much indeed. I feel sorry because I cannot accept both answers. Hope Davide won't get angry if I keep Norbert's answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @Romeo No, I wont!

Answer (score 4):

A quick proof of this can be given using the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, which is covered in Rudin and a number of other texts. Write your limit as $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_\mathbb R \sin(nx)\frac{\phi(x) - \phi(0)\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)}{x}\, dx 
+ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_\mathbb R \sin(nx)\frac{\phi(0)\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)}{x}\, dx $$
Here $\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)$ denotes the characteristic function of $[-1,1]$. Since $\phi(x) \in C_c^1({\mathbb R})$, the function ${\displaystyle \frac{\phi(x) - \phi(0)\chi_{[-1,1]}(x)}{x}}$ is a bounded function with compact support; the only place you have to worry about is $x = 0$ and you can use the mean value theorem for example to show it's bounded near $x = 0$. Since the function is bounded function with compact support it is in $L^1$, which is enough to apply the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma and say the first term goes to zero. As for the second term, after changing variables to $y = nx$ we may rewrite it as 
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_\mathbb R \sin(y)\frac{\phi(0)\chi_{[-n,n]}(y)}{y}\, dy $$
$$= \phi(0)\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-n}^n \frac{\sin(y)}{y}\, dy $$
$$= \phi(0)\int_\mathbb R \frac{\sin(y)}{y}\, dy $$
$$= \pi \phi(0)$$
So this will be the overall limit.

Comment: Nice, and doesn't use further derivatives than first one.

Comment: Only need that $\phi(x)$ is a compactly supported Lipschitz function...

Comment: If you assume it, then the argument for the convergence on $0$ may not follow by mean value theorem, but just using boundedness of the ratio $\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}x$.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $\phi(x)$ is supported in $|x|< L$. Since $\phi$ is differentiable, $\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}$ is bounded and therefore integrable on $|x|<L$.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\pi\,\phi(0)+\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin(nx)\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\pi\,\phi(0)+\color{#C00000}{\int_{-L}^L\sin(nx)\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&-2\,\phi(0)\color{#00A000}{\int_{nL}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
\end{align}
$$
As $n\to\infty$, the red integral vanishes by the [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) and the green integral vanishes because [The Dirichlet Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral) converges. This leaves us with
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi\,\phi(0)
$$

Answer (score 3):

We can assume WLOG that $\phi\in C^3_c(\Bbb R)$, since this subset is dense for the supremum norm and $\frac{\sin x}x$ is integrable over compact subsets. We have 
$$\phi(x)-\phi(0)=x\phi'(0)+x\int_0^1(1-s)\phi''(sx),$$
hence, if the support of $\phi$ is contained in $[-R,R]$
\begin{align}
\small \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}x\phi(x)dx&=\small\phi(0)\int_{-R}^R\frac{\sin(nx)}xdx+\phi'(0)\int_{-R}^R\sin(nx)dx+\int_{—R}^R\sin(nx)\int_0^1(1-s)\phi''(sx)dsdx\\
&=\small\phi(0)\int_{-nR}^{nR}\frac{\sin t}tdt-\left[\frac{\cos(nx)}n\int_0^1(1-s)\phi''(sx)ds\right]_{-R}^R+\int_{—R}^R\frac{\cos(nx)}n\int_0^1
s(1-s)\phi'''(sx)dsdx
\end{align}
We have 
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_{-nR}^{nR}\frac{\sin t}tdt=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin t}tdt;$$
$$\left|\left[\frac{\cos(nx)}n\int_0^1(1-s)\phi''(sx)ds\right]_{-R}^R\right|\leq \frac 2n\sup_{t\in \Bbb R}|\phi''(t)|,$$
and 
$$\left|\int_{—R}^R\frac{\cos(nx)}n\int_0^1
s(1-s)\phi'''(sx)dsdx\right|\leq \frac{2R}n\sup_{t\in \Bbb R}|\phi'''(t)|$$